# Why isn't the second loop running more than once?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm writing a script that queries an API multiple times based on an ID. The odd part is when I just log the ID, the script seems to run fine. When I try to loop through the response from the API, it only happens once.

Here's what I'm working with

```
// Makes the request by ID    
function requestById() {
  var ids = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow() - 1).getValues()
  for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    submitById(ids[i][0])
  }
}

// Fetches the results from the API
function submitById(x) {
  var url = {api URL} + x
  
  const options = {
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: { Authorization: "Basic " + b64apiKey, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  }

  var res = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options))

  Logger.log(x)
  
  for (i = 0; i < res.tasks[0].result[0].items.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(res.tasks[0].result[0].items[i])
  }
```

The really weird part is that if I *just* log the IDs in the second function, it shows that the first loop in requestById() runs the appropriate amount of times. If I run a loop on the result in the second function... it only runs for the first ID and none of the others.

I'm not sure why it's not working only when I run a loop on the result. I use a similar format elsewhere in my project and it works *fine*

How do I get this to run for every ID?

PS. I have an API key and {api URL} in my code is an *actual* URL. These are just placeholders for this question. Similarly, sheet *is* defined elsewhere

Comment: It's hard to say without the  response data in front of us.  And your code is not reproducible.  Perhaps you could read [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are actually using your showing script, when I saw your showing script, `i` is used with `for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {,,,}` in the function `requestById()`. And, `i` of `for (i = 0; i < res.tasks[0].result[0].items.length; i++) {` is also used in the function `submitById(x)` as `i = 0`. I'm worried that this might be the reason for your current issue. In the case of `i = 0`, the `i` in the function `requestById()` might be used. By this, the index of the loop might not be able to be correctly run. In order to avoid this, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```js
for (i = 0; i < res.tasks[0].result[0].items.length; i++) {
  Logger.log(res.tasks[0].result[0].items[i])
}
```

##### To:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < res.tasks[0].result[0].items.length; i++) {
  Logger.log(res.tasks[0].result[0].items[i])
}
```

or

```js
for (var j = 0; j < res.tasks[0].result[0].items.length; j++) {
  Logger.log(res.tasks[0].result[0].items[j])
}
```

#### Note:

- But, I have no information about `ids.length` and `res.tasks[0].result[0].items.length`. So, if this modification was not useful, can you provide the values of them?

Comment: My goodness, this was exactly it! Once I changed i to y in the second loop it worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jeff Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.